# Can not find any provider supporting AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING for a struts application . My JDK version is 1.4 and weblogic 8

Tags: java, security

I was trying to encrypt data using AES128 algorithm. However, with the following exception has occurred.

When i am debugging it as java application , it is working as fine.but when deploying it over weblogic server , i am getting 
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithException :Can not find any security provider supporting AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: So use something that's less than 14 years old?

Comment: Beside the fact that you should consider to update, you might use http://bouncycastle.org/java.html as provider.

Comment: The exception named is missing from the post. Please fill it in and maybe give reasons why you are constrained to old versions (there may be legitimate reasons, but we cannot know). Thanks.

Comment: i am getting java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmyException. i checked the security provider and below were listed-  SunJSSE version1.41, SunRsaSign version 1.0,SunJCE version 1.4 , SunJGSS version 1.0. Do I still need to add Bouncy Castle ?

Comment: Don't post a stacktrace as image. Instead edit a question and paste text code of the satacktrace.

Comment: When i am debugging the application as java application, code is working fine. But when i am deploying the code over weblogic server, i am getting java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException.can anyone please suggest?